# "What's New in this Version" specified in iTunesConnect does not appear in "Version History" of the App Store

Tags: ios6, app-store, version, app-store-connect, xcode4.5

When uploading an iOS app, I always specify information under the section of "What's New in this Version" found in iTunes Connect's page. Since iOS6, App Store displays information about version history of every app. So, I guess this information comes from "What's New in this Version" that each submission contains. However, I could not find this version history for my app. Version History of my app just contains version number and date published only.

What else do I have to do to make this information available in Version History of the App Store?

Note: I upload an app via Xcode's Organizer, not via Application Loader.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and I believe it is a problem in the itunesconnect. I have an app in appstore with 4 different versions. Up until now, the version history was empty. Today, the history for the last version just showed up (last version is updated a couple of weeks back). BTW, I am pretty sure that I've written description to "what is new in this version" box.